# What's the easiest way to save a GIFV as a simple GIF?

Tags: google-chrome, mp4, gif, webm

Usually I open the context menu right clicking on the image. Now theres no option for "save image as", just options for the WEBM/MP4 format.

Comment: If the source link is a gifv file like those from tumblr, you can save the gifv in your disk, rename it to webp (the file content would be starting with RIFF>WEBPVP8X...) and convert  this webp to gif using a site like https://ezgif.com/webp-to-gif the final result I got was a working animated gif

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`GIFV` isn't a `GIF` at all, in the traditional sense anyway. It's actually a video file.

Here's what I read from [Imgur's blog post introducing GIFV](https://imgur.com/blog/2014/10/09/introducing-gifv/):

> The cornerstone of Project GIFV is a platform-wide upgrade to
>   automatically **convert uploaded GIF files on the fly into the WebM or
>   MP4 video formats**, depending on browser support.
>   
> ... 
>   Project GIFV **implements video in a way that looks and behaves exactly like a GIF**.

If you right-clicked on a `GIFV` and selected `Open link in new tab` (or a similar option) you'd see that Imgur creates a minimalistic web page that it *seems* like you just opened a `GIF` in a new tab but right-click anywhere on the page and select `View Source` and you'll see that isn't the case.

To answer your question, the easiest way to save a `GIFV` as a `GIF` (if it is hosted on [Imgur.com](http://imgur.com)) is to open it in a new tab and click on the download link at the bottom.
[image: download GIFV]

If the `GIFV` is hosted on another site (not that I know of any other sites hosting GIFV) you can use either of the two online video conversion services:

1. [MP4 to GIF](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/mp4-to-gif/)
2. [WEBM to GIF](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/webm-to-gif/)

**NOTE:** Downloading a `GIFV` as a proper `GIF` will most certainly increase the file size by a big margin. If you'd rather download the `WEBM` or `MP4` video instead, you may right click on the `GIFV` and select `Save video as...` (or a similar option).

Comment: The download button just downloaded a gif**v** for me. :(

Comment: @ruffin it seems to still work for me. Could you share the imgur link to the GIF you're trying to download?

Comment: This example does not behave like you describe: https://imgur.com/Bwgxvhe ... I have used it b4 and I know works sometmes, ijdk what the cause of the difference is.

Comment: @Rondo The other way is to just add a `.gifv` at the end of the URL. That works for this.

Comment: No, it doesn't... If you add the gifv extension to the url I posted you get a download link that only downloads as mp4

Comment: @Rondo You're right. It doesn't work with this GIF. Maybe Imgur changed something on their end.

Answer (score 16):

For Imgur URLs, if you remove the V from `.gifv` then you will get the original animated GIF.

(This might not be "a simple GIF" but could be a large file, as [explained on Imgur's blog](http://imgur.com/blog/2014/10/09/introducing-gifv/). Like in [http://i.imgur.com/zvATqgs.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/zvATqgs.gifv) the embedded video is 3.4 MB, but the original animated GIF [http://i.imgur.com/zvATqgs.gif](https://i.imgur.com/zvATqgs.gif) is 46.7 MB.)

Comment: That's not true. A `.gifv` file is a video file, not a `.gif` image.

Comment: @slhck Actually, if he meant changing `.gifv` to `.gif` in the imgur.com URL pointing to the GIF, Imgur would deliver the uncompressed GIF instead of the video file.

Comment: Ah, you're right @Vinayak, that must have been what they meant.

Comment: @Vinayak That gave me a single-frame gif.

Comment: @ruffin do you have the link to it?

Answer (score 1):

Renaming .gifv to .gif extension on the address bar does not work for me.

Right click on the .gifv and copy video url, this will copy it's url with .mp4 extension.

Use `wget` or other tools to download the file. It usually redirects back to the .gifv link on a browser.

Comment: This won't work if revisiting the url will generate a new file.